# TypeScript error: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export const PageViewTracker = ({ children }: ReactNode): ReactElement => {

    usePageView();

    return children;
};
```

**Problem:**

This function returns error »*Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'*«

**My approach to solution:**

I tried out several types but only *any* works which is not what I want. Usually I used ReactNode for children props and it worked fine. In this case TypeScript seems to have issues.

Comment: You want `({ children }: { children: ReactNode })`. The way you wrote it is trying to type the destructured props object as a ReactNode, which props is obviously not.

Comment: Just remove the brackets from children altogether

Answer (score 248, accepted):

**React >=18**

In React 18 the `FunctionalComponent` interface has changed to become:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
    displayName?: string | undefined;
}
```

Note that the `PropsWithChildren` type is omitted from the `props` type of a FunctionalComponent after React 18, this means that you have to include the `children` prop yourself:

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const PageViewTracker: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
}
```

The reason why they removed the implicit `children` prop can be found [here](https://solverfox.dev/writing/no-implicit-children/). ([source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210) of React 18's Type definition release notes).

The `PropsWithChildren` type is still available within the typings of React, so if you still want to optionally have `children` as props just like versions before React 18, you can still do:

```
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

interface Props {
  foo: string;
}

export const PageViewTracker: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({ children, foo }) => {
}
```

The type definition of `PropsWithChildren` is:

```
type PropsWithChildren<P = unknown> = P & { children?: ReactNode | undefined };
```

---

**React <=17**

The reason why you're getting that error is because you're giving the 'ReactNode' interface to an object (`{}: Type`). `children` itself is of the type ReactNode:

`type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode };`

You should give your PageViewTracker the `FunctionComponent` (or its alias `FC`) type.

```
export const PageViewTracker: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
   ...
}
```

which has the following interface:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

So by default it accepts the `children` prop which has the type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: You're not necessarily wrong, but that isn't the problem with the code the OP posted...

Comment: If you are using a Forward Ref syntax, the code is

const Menu= React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, PropsWithChildren<React.HtmlHTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>>((props, ref) => {..........etc

You have to tell the generic forwardRef what type your properties are, then you don't need to syntactically do that on the function def, it's inferred.  The first generic T is the type of the ref, and the 2nd is the type of the component properties.

Comment: This worked for getting rid of the "Children does not exist" error I was seeing that prevented compile in React Native with React 18.2.0. After destructuring out {children} as a property in my custom provider function that makes use of children this works.

e.g.
```const SomeReactComponent = ({ children }) => (<Component>{children}</Component>)```

Answer (score 51):

Important note: after react 18.0.0 they make you include children in each FC interface.

```
interface MyButtonProps {
  color: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Then you can just pass props like older versions.

```
const Button:React.FC<MyButtonProps> = (props) => {
    //use children with {props.children} just like before  
}
```

From [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-typescript-definitions)

Comment: Thanks - maybe consider update the doc link with correct anchor: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-typescript-definitions

Answer (score 23):

For   "@types/react": "17.0.43", or less than 18

```
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";


const BaseLayout: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>      
    </>
  );
};

export default BaseLayout;
```

For "@types/react" > 18

```
interface BaseLayoutProps {
  children?: ReactNode;
}

const BaseLayout: FunctionComponent<BaseLayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>          
    </>
  );
};
```

But for some cases, you still need to use `FunctionComponent`. For example:

```
interface ArtListProps {
  arts: Art[];
  children: FunctionComponent;
}

export default function ArtList({ arts, children }: ArtListProps) {
  return (
    <section className="grid md:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-4 mb-5">
      {/* this is called render prop */}
      {arts.map((art) => children(art))}
    </section>
  );
}
```

If you pass `ReactNode`, you get error "type ReactNode is not callable`

Answer (score 7):

You can simply write it like this:

```
export const PageViewTracker = ({ children }: {children: ReactNode}): ReactElement => {

    usePageView();

    return children;
};
```

Note that I change `({ children }: ReactNode)` to `({ children }: {children: ReactNode})`

Comment: This works as expected, but what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 6):

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export const MenuLateral: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export const PageViewTracker= ( { children }: {children: ReactNode} ) => {

        usePageView();

        return children;
    };
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score 2):

As Dan mentioned in one of his tweet,
"f you’re getting TypeScript errors about the `children` prop when upgrading @types/react to 18.0.0, the fix looks like this. You need to declare them in the props type as a regular prop, with a type of React.ReactNode."

[React 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mmPK.jpg)

You can check his tweet here: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1512833611401150474

or The stackoverflow thread here:
[React 18 TypeScript children FC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788254/react-18-typescript-children-fc/71809927#71809927)

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate it's type in generic type arguments:

```js
import React, {ReactNode} from "react";

const Hello: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({children}) => {
    return <React.Fragment>
        Hello {children}
    </React.Fragment>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";

interface Layout {
  children?: ReactNode;
}

const Layout: React.FC<Layout> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
};
export default Layout;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).