# React Typescript prop works fine, but returns error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created component and I'm passing props to styled components, it works fine, but at first prop it always get this error.

**Component**

```
type WelcomeProps = { 
    image: String,
    color: String
}

const StyledWelcome = styled.section`
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: ${props => props.color};
    background: ${props => `url(${props.image}) no-repeat center`};
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
`


const WelcomeContainer = styled.div`
    width: 1350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
`

export const WelcomeFullscreen = (props: WelcomeProps) => (
    <StyledWelcome image={props.image} color={props.color}>
        <WelcomeContainer/>
    </StyledWelcome>
);
```

**Usage:**

```
<WelcomeFullscreen image={HomepageImage} color="#000">
```

**Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're passing an array of elements as children to your `WelcomeFullscreen` components in your `Welcome.tsx` file somewhere

If you define your `WelcomeFullscreen` component as an actual React FunctionComponent, `children` is always allowed as prop.

`const WelcomeFullscreen: React.FC<WelcomeProps> = (props) => ()...`

I answered a similar question here: [TypeScript error: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106742/typescript-error-property-children-does-not-exist-on-type-reactnode/59106817#59106817).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to define the type of the component styled by `styled-components`

```
const StyledWelcome = styled(div)<WelcomeProps>`
  ...
`
```

Refer: styled-components document of [using custom props with typescript](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props)

> If you are passing custom properties to your styled component it's a good idea to pass type arguments to tagged template

Comment: This helps with mixture of answer below. Thanks!