# Access the prop of a child in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I know React and I'm trying to learn typescript. I'm migrating a previous project to typescript and I'm having some issues. I want to access a prop of a child in the parent to do some stuff with it but typescript is not letting me. I've only found how to pass children declaring them as a ReactNode but not how to use the children props.

My code:

This is the child element

```
interface DataColumnProps {
  label: string;
}

const DataColumn = (props: DataColumnProps) => {
  return <>...not important...<>;
};

export default DataColumn;
```

And this is the one where I'm trying to access the label prop from the children passed

```
interface DataTableProps {
  children: ReactNode[];
}

const DataTable = <Data extends object>({
  children
}: DataTableProps) => {
  const columns = Children.map(children, child => {
    const { label } = child; // This is where my issue is happening
    return <span>{label}<span/>;
  })

  return (
    <div>{columns.map(c => c}</div>
  );
```

The error I get is the following:

[image: typescript error]

Here is the page using both components

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <DataTable columns={columns} data={data}>
        <DataColumn label="To convert" />
        <DataColumn label="Into" />
        <DataColumn label="Multiply by" />
      </DataTable>
    </>
  );
};
```

I've tried, based in some googling, exporting the DataColumnProps and declaring the children as an array of ReactElement of DataColumnProps, but the issue remains:

```
interface DataTableProps<Data extends object> {
  children: ReactElement<DataColumnProps>[];
  data: Data[];
  columns: ColumnDef<Data, any>[];
}
```

I'm using **React 18**

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: `I want to access a prop of a child in the parent`  this doesn't really make much sense. The parent is the one who passes props **to** the child, it should already have access to any prop values its children may be receiving (unless the children are getting those props from other sources like HOCs or Redux wrapper). Your example is super basic, the `DataColumn` component should be controlling what it renders - maybe a description of the more complex functionality you're trying to recreate would help?

Comment: Just Go through this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106742/typescript-error-property-children-does-not-exist-on-type-reactnode
I hope you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a few things:

[Check Stack blitz full working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-r3qjxk?file=App.tsx)

You need to say the datatable children are of elements that have DataColumnProps

```js
interface DataTableProps {
  children: React.ReactElement<DataColumnProps>[];
}
```

Then reading the prop is safe since typescript is asured that all the children will have the label prop in props

```js
const DataTable = <Data extends object>({ children }: DataTableProps) => {
  const columns = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return <span>{child.props.label}</span>;
  });

  return <div>{columns.map((c) => c)}</div>;
};
```

[Check Stack blitz full working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-r3qjxk?file=App.tsx)

Comment: My issue is that I didn't access the props in the child. If you read my question I tried to do the children elements of type DataColumn props but I was trying to extract the label from the `child` instead of `child.props`. This helped me realize that. Thank you